# Hide a gridview column header base on the value of a code behind variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have set this variable in my code behind:

```
Protected showHidePrice As Boolean = True

Property ShowHidePricePty() As Boolean 
    Get
        Return showHidePrice
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        showHidePrice = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and have this in markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblExtended_Price" Text='<%# Eval("Extended_Price")%>' Visible='<%#Me.ShowHidePricePty%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

with this I can hide or show the **content** of the column "Extended Price", but can not do the same for its **column header**.

Is there any way to hide the column header too using something like this `ShowHeader='<%#Me.ShowHidePricePty%>'` (not working for me right now)?

I know I can accomplish this using methods like onRowDataBound, for instance, but I would like to use that property, in case it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done inline with the HeaderTemplate, the problem however is on which row you base the showing or hiding of the Header Text.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <%# Convert.ToBoolean(((System.Data.DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).Rows[0][0]) ? "HeaderText" : "" %>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("column1") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Or with a method like your `ShowHidePricePty`

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <%# ShowHidePricePty() ? "HeaderText" : "" %>
</HeaderTemplate>
```